# Integrating Angular2, Redux and JWT

Tags: angular, redux, jwt

I have got a problem with an application where I am using Angular2 and Redux. I decided to use Redux Observable (the natural order of things since Angular2 uses RxJS) but RxJS is quite tricky for me.

I am handling all async/side effects by epics. It is clear for me but now I need to add JWT to my application and I do not know where I should put my code for saving and reading token?

I do this actions:

1. Dispatch LOGIN_REQUEST.
2. In epic I make async request to the backend API and get email and token in a response.
3. Depends on result, I dispatch LOGIN_SUCCESS or LOGIN_ERROR.

I think that there should be an extra point between 2. and 3. but I am not sure about that. Should I add logic for saving  JWT token to the epic?

I will be grateful for all advice about that and integrating JWT with Redux at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the session and save the token to localStorage in your epic - this is where you should handling all your side effects.

```
  login = ( action$ ) => {
    return action$.ofType(SessionActions.LOGIN_USER)
      .flatMap(( {user} ) => {
        return this.sessionService.login(user)
          .do(payload => {
            this.sessionService.setSession(payload.json());
          }).map(result => ({
            type: SessionActions.LOGIN_SUCCESS,
            payload: result.json()
          })).catch(error => Observable.of({
            type: SessionActions.LOGIN_ERROR,
            payload: error.json()
          }));
      });
  }
```

SessionService:

```
  setSession( user ) {
    this.storage.setItem('auth-user', user);
  }

  isLoggedIn() : boolean {
    return !!this.storage.getItem('auth-user');
  }
```

Comment: Nice! That what I am asking for. Could you show me session service, please. I would love to see how you do it :)

Comment: It's simple localStorage.setItem function, that's depends on how you implement your session validation.